# Django - Is overriding TemplateView.get with different signature a bad practice?

Tags: django, pylint

I wrote a Django application with a `JobView` inherited from `TemplateView`. The get method needs an additional argument (job_id) which is in the URL. Basically, my `urls.py` looks like this:

```
# urls.py
from django.conf import url
from .views import JobView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^job/(?P<job_id>[0-9]+)$',
        JobView.as_view())
```

The views.py contains the definition of JobView:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse

class JobView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request, job_id):
        # Some stuff
        return HttpResponse("something")
```

When checking this code with pylint, I get this error: `[arguments-differ] Arguments number differs from overriden 'get' method`.

To fit the `TemplateView.get` method, the definition of `JobView.get` should be:

```
class JobView(TemplateView):
    def get(self, request):
        # Some stuff
```

Is overriding with an other signature a bad practice? If yes, how am I supposed to implement such a thing?

Comment: It's not bad, but if you're overriding `get` to return a response directly there doesn't seem to be any point at all in overriding TemplateView rather than the base View.

Comment: You are right on this point, but some code is missing, making the `TemplateView` meaningful. However `base.View` does not have a `get()` method, removing the issue. It could be a good solution if my code is a bad practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature should be the same, but you can add custom args and kwargs if you pop them when calling the super class method. The actual method signature of a View (subclass) is get(self, request, *args, **kwargs).